# How Reflection effects the Design of an application

Tags: java, reflection

I have read a some interview questions on java and i found below.

> Qus. Is It Good to use Reflection in an application ? Ans. No, It's
>   like challenging the design of application

I need to clarify the above answer more as I learn reflection is a powerful feature of Java.

What is meant by challenging the design?

What scenario we have to practically use reflection in an application?

Comment: If it wasn't that good, then you should avoid using frameworks like Spring, Hibernate, MyBatis and many others...

Comment: does those frameworks address what achieve by reflection in another way?

Comment: Let me see: using specific constructors **at runtime**, injecting fields dynamically **at runtime**, execute methods of a class **at runtime**, creating proxy classes on the fly that implement/extend a specific interface/class that will wrap your direct class **at runtime**... I guess they use reflection a lot.

Comment: true. actually i also dont agree with the answer either. just want to clarify.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza - There is a big difference between using reflection yourself, and using a framework that uses reflection.

Comment: @StephenC I know, but if the question says that you should not use reflection in the app, then you should not allow frameworks that use reflection in the app as well because they will use reflection behind the scenes. It's like asking *can you print the elements of an array without traversing them?* The answer will be *No, you can't* but some people may say *you can by using `Arrays.toString(yourArray)` but this method will iterate the array behind the scenes :)

Comment: IMO you should be **very careful** when using reflection directly in your app, specially because it's easy to cause a mess. I would use it in very specific use cases depending on the context e.g. reading an [EDI file](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electronic_data_interchange) and mapping it to a custom structure that may vary depending on the data contained in the EDI.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Challenging the design means you can:

1. Access private members of a class using reflection.
2. You can instantiate those classes that you are not supposed to, example: you can instantiate `java.lang.System` using reflection which you are not intended to.
3. And many other things that the original programmer of the API doesn't want you to. Or you can do things you should not as far as possible.

Though reflection is useful in certain cases:

1. Like when using `FXML`, your interpreter dynamically loads the `FXML` file and sets attributes to your nodes dynamically. using reflection.
2. If you have ever programmed for android, you must know that programmers design the `view` of their apps using `.xml` files. Even in this case, your widgets are loaded dynamically using reflection. Basic example, in android:

   ```
   <Button  ...
        android:onClick="callMe" />
   ```

Then you write the `callMe(View view)` method in the `.java` file. This listener is added to the button using reflection.

3. Frameworks like Spring, Hibernate, etc also use reflection for their processing.

So there are both pros and cons of reflection.

You might want to refer [this](http://www.coderanch.com/t/533568/java/java/Reflection-API-pros-cons) for further information